# Vocar datos de Dataset a Crystal Reports

Tags: vb.net

Estimados amigos buen día,
Soy un novato en VB.net y estoy elaborando una aplicativo que extrae registros de un archivo Excel (No uso base de datos convencionales). He llegado a almacenar la información de estos registros de Excel en una tabla de un Dataset. Necesito saber cómo hago para volcar la data de la tabla "Cliente" del Dataset "**Base.xsd**" al reporte previamente creado/configurado con Crystal Reports. El reporte se llama **rptCartas.rpt** y como ya lo mencioné he asignado los campos correspondientes (de la tabla Clientes, del Dataset) en su respectivo lugar dentro del reporte.
Adjunto imagen de mi código y el mensaje de error: gracias por cualquier tipo de ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: Imagen:]

Comment: Que error te da, eso es muy imortante!

Comment: Ricky te ha faltado solo un pequeñito detalle, en que linea específica te da el error? Sobre .SetDataSource??

Comment: Revisa cada variable en el código que está comentado, a mi me parece que el DataSource no tiene tablas. El error indica que la dll `crdb_adoplus.dll` no existe en esa ruta, comprueba que la dll exista y coloca la referencia en tu proyecto.

Comment: Puede ser como lo dice Mauricio tu referencia al Crystal pero a pesar de ello también debes colocar lo que puse en mi respuesta

Comment: Amigos, ya funciona, lo que ahora estoy buscando es la forma de cómo obtener todos los registros de la tabla "Cliente" del Dataset, porque de los más de 1000 registros solo me muestra 24 registros en el reporte.. Pero lo concerniente a este Post, ya está resuelto gracias al archivo de conexión app.Config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizás algo que te esté faltando es una definición en el **app.config** de tu Proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La linea que debes agregar es:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
```

Si no tienes un app.config en tu proyecto lo puedes agregar:
Click secundario en el proyecto - Agregar - Nuevo Elemento - Archivo de configuración de aplicaciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias Agustin M. realmente funcionó... ahora surgió otro problema, pero no corresponde con el presente post. Muchas gracias, saludos y hasta la próxima.

Comment: No hay problema. Es uno de los primeros problemas con los que nos encontramos todos los que lidiamos con CR. Y hasta que a veces creo un nuevo proyecto con CR y me olvido de esto hasta que me salta un error como el tuyo jaja! Saludos.